# Alarm Manager on Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I know there are questions and solutions already for alarm manager and I have searched a lot, but I am facing same problem.

My issue is I'm adding multiple alarms with a unique Id every time and canceling them with the same ids. All alarms are working fine while adding and deleting, but an alarm keeps on ringing after irregular intervals.

Here is my code for setting an alarm.

```
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmSer.class);
    next =  myRandom.nextInt();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),next, i, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, firstWake, pendingIntent);
```

Code for cancelling the `alarm.values` of next and alarmReqCode is the same for a particular alarm.

```
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmSer.class);
  alarmReqCode=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
  TodoDbAdapter.ALARMCODE)));
  PendingIntent  pendingIntent=
  PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),alarmReqCode, i, 0);
  am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

In [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file) I'm getting this:

```
 03-19 11:43:03.475: V/AlarmManager(21088): waitForAlarm result :4
 03-19 11:43:03.480: V/AlarmManager(21088): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
```

Comment: your missing `PendingIntent pendingIntent =` when canceling.  Is that just a transcription error?

Comment: just edited my code .

Comment: can you explain what you mean by alarm keeps ringing after irregular intervals?  You are not setting a repeating alarm.

Comment: I'm not setting repeating alarm, alarms working fine they are ringing on a defined time and if i delete them they will not appear but i keep getting alarms after that with not any regular behavior or interval which i didn't set .

Comment: And I'm getting this in logcat .                                    03-19 11:43:03.475: V/AlarmManager(21088): waitForAlarm result :4
03-19 11:43:03.480: V/AlarmManager(21088): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP

Comment: Try using `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see whats happening with the alarms when you set/cancel them.  Also, your pending intent flag is 0 which seems to be undefined?  Try one of the PendingIntent flags such as `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: Do you get the alarm once you go back to the app? or if you stay in the app and don't quit you still keep getting ringings?